# What do boot option noapic and noacpi actually do?

Tags: linux-kernel

I had issues booting Ubuntu on a machine and adding noapic and noacpi to vmlinuz boot option solved the issue.

I am aware of noapic is to disable interrupt remap and noacpi is related to power config, but what do they actually do in linux kernel? Do they skip loading specific modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Linux Admin Guide Kernel Parameters documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html),

```
noapic          [SMP,APIC] Tells the kernel to not make use of any
                IOAPICs that may be present in the system.
pci=noacpi      [X86] Do not use ACPI for IRQ routing
            or for PCI scanning.
```

From a programmatic perspective noapic sets the variable disable_apic to 1 in  [setup_disableapic of /arch/x86/kernel/apic/apic.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/apic/apic.c#L2660) which results in `apic_intr_mode_select` returning APIC_PIC, which results in the [apic_intr_mode_init](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/apic/apic.c#L1350) function leaving the PIC in PIC mode(8259) and in  `default_setup_apic_routing` not being called.

And `pci=noacpi` calls results in `parse_pci(char *arg)` in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/arch/x86/kernel/acpi/boot.c#L1689, calling [acpi_disable_pci](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/arch/x86/include/asm/acpi.h#L72) which sets `acpi_pci_disabled` to 1 and calls `acpi_noirq_set` to do as specified by the documentation.

For additional background information, see the following resources [What are the "acpi" and "noapic" kernel boot options? Redhat Knowledge Base](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/58790) and [IRQ, ACPI and APIC and the Linux kernel](https://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/irq_acpi_apic)

Comment: Very interesting. Could you elaborate on the side effects of using `noapic`? The linked documents do explain a bit, but not much more than "Disabling APIC removes the ability to make use of IRQ sharing or device IRQ remapping."